# windows-x86_64/bin/clang is unable to create an executable file. C compiler test failed

Tags: windows, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg, cygwin-64

I want to build ffmpeg_6.0 in android studio with ndk_r26b, windows os.

trying to run following script on cygwin 64 terminal.

```js
#!/bin/bash
NDK=D:/Android/ndk_r26b
HOST=windows-x86_64
SYSROOT=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST/sysroot
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST
function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--target-os=android \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--enable-cross-compile \
--cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-symver \
--arch=$ARCH \
--cpu=$CPU \
--cc=$CC \
--cxx=$CXX \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \


$NDK/prebuilt/$HOST/bin/make clean
$NDK/prebuilt/$HOST/bin/make -j3
$NDK/prebuilt/$HOST/bin/make install
}

#armv8-a
ARCH=arm64
CPU=armv8-a
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/clang
CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/clang++
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-androideabi
#ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

cygwin terminal error [image: Cygwin terminal error image]

Error: windows-x86_64/bin/clang is unable to create an executable file. C compiler test failed.

I have downloaded cygwin make, clang, gcc, g++ , etc.
also set clang environment variable cygwin environment

also downloaded minGW 86_64, and added MinGW\bin path to Environment variable.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: One weird thing I see is the ARCH, it's not the same as ABI, I think for arm64 it's aarch64.
Haven't tried to compile with an NDK, the easiest way for me is to cross compile from linux (from a Virtualbox environment for example), much smoother. So not sure if in your case a linux toolchain has to be used. Check this resource too: https://yesimroy.gitbooks.io/android-note/content/compile_ffmpeg_for_android.html.
Also, in general to check the exact configuration errors you have to review the ffbuild/config.log as said in your console output. It should tell why it cannot create an executable.